# Delete xml Node by name and update it

Tags: java, xml, nodes

I have a following xml file.

```
<abc>
  <sample name="xyz">
    <a>....</a>
  </sample>
  <sample name="pqr">
    <a>....</a>
  </sample>
</abc>
```

I need to delete `<sample name="xyz">` only but when I click on delete button it deletes all `<sample>` Node but I need to only delete the node which name is "xyz". After deleting I need to update my xml file automatically.
Here is my code I used but isn't working for me

```
try{
   String xmlFile = "C:/practise.xml";
   File file = new File(xmlFile);
    String remElement = "sample";
   if (file.exists()){
   DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
   Document doc = builder.parse(xmlFile);
   TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
   Transformer tFormer = tFactory.newTransformer();
   Element element = (Element)doc.getElementsByTagName(remElement).item(0); 
   element.getParentNode().removeChild(element);
    doc.normalize();
    Source source = new DOMSource(doc);
   Result dest = new StreamResult(System.out);
   tFormer.transform(source, dest);
   System.out.println("jhala re delete");
   //createOutputFile("C:/MyTestbeds/TestBed1.xml", transformToString(doc));
}
else{
     System.out.println("File not found!");
   }
}
catch (Exception e){
System.err.println(e);

}
}
```

I don't understand what's wrong in my code. I also need to update my xml file when I delete the first node.

Comment: Where exactly in your code do you indicate you're looking for the `<sample>` element named **`xyz`**? I somehow fail to see any mention of `xyz` in your code.

Comment: i know i am not mention this because i don't know hot to use this?

Comment: In your question, you wrote *I don't understand what's wrong in my code.*, but apparently, you know very well what is wrong with/missing in your code. Please change your question to ask more specifically for what is missing (Conditional execution? Retrieving an attribute value? Finding elements with a given attribute value? ...?). Also, please ask only one question at a time; for other issues (update the Xml file), open a separate SO question.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me. Try to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) illustrating your issue.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class TestXML {

    private static final String XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n<abc>\r\n" + "<sample name=\"xyz\">\r\n"
            + "    <a>....</a>\r\n" + "  </sample>\r\n" + "  <sample name=\"pqr\">\r\n" + "    <a>....</a>\r\n" + "  </sample>\r\n"
            + "</abc>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String remElement = "sample";
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(XML.getBytes("UTF-8")));
            TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer tFormer = tFactory.newTransformer();
            Element element = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName(remElement).item(0);
            element.getParentNode().removeChild(element);
            doc.normalize();
            Source source = new DOMSource(doc);
            Result dest = new StreamResult(System.out);
            tFormer.transform(source, dest);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```